# How to make vectors be of same length in my Matlab script?

Tags: matlab, vector, variable-length

I am trying to plot some data.  The script I wrote below has worked fine before, but now I have no idea why it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
x = [335,41,14,18,15,9,7,9,20607,5,5,143,3,5,72,134,2,28,172,3,72,173,280,186,20924,1,1,22,3,3,1,2,13,1,3,2,11,66,12983,176,123,192,64,258,182,123,299,58,198,7,113,342,72,8376,122,20,19,2,3,28,8,36,8,56,43,2,48,127,395,4664,186,46,236,219,258,69,203,189,169,72,100,78,109,46,112,3929,272,40,4,31,2,97,36,5,35,56,2,237,1672,256,224,28,163,341,151,263,157,397,94,380,173,75,87,272,1194,133,6,112,1,6,2,26,25,64,8,40,57,106,525,150,248,125,269,264,256,357,153,64,152,283,1,2,2,454,154,39,1,1,64,151,242,1,18,99,1,36,607,55,54,110,225,108,37,1,144,162,137,107,21,360,362,18,51,25,43,1,3,6,1,27,7,45,326,32,103,50,124,155,39,180,143,33,116,46,7,151,120,19,4,2,4,110,2,7,4,9,4,27,216,323,148,1,1,2,1,47,113,150,1,2,144,16,4827,1,1,1,14];
size = length(x);
disp(size);
z = 0;
for i = 1:size
    z = z + 1;
    y(i) = z;
end
scatter(x,y);
```

This code should ensure that `y` is of same length as `x` as we are only filling in `y` as long as x is (since we are using a for loop from 1 through to `size`, where `size` is basically the number of indices in `x`), but I keep getting this error. I checked with `disp` and it turns out that my x and y vectors have different lengths, x is 227 and y is 256. Can anyone help me out with this trivial issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because `y` was created to be a different size before you ran that piece of code you showed us.  Somewhere in your script before you call this piece of code, `y` was created to be a 256 element vector and now you are reusing this variable in this part of the code by populating elements in the `y` vector.  The variable `x` has 227 elements and the loop you wrote will change `y`'s first 227 elements as you have looped for as many times as there are elements in `x`.  However, the remaining 29 elements are still there from before.  The reusing of the variable `y` is probably why your script is failing as now the sizes between both variables are not the same.  As such, **explicitly** recreate `y` before calling `scatter`.

Actually, that `for` loop is not needed at all.  The purpose of the loop is to create an increasing array from 1 up to as many elements as you have in `x`.

Just do this instead:

```
y = 1:size;
```

I also do not like that you are creating a variable called `size`.  It is overshadowing the function [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html), which finds the number of elements in each dimension that the input array contains.

With the recommendations I've stated above, replace your entire code with this:

```
x = [335,41,14,18,15,9,7,9,20607,5,5,143,3,5,72,134,2,28,172,3,72,173,280,186,20924,1,1,22,3,3,1,2,13,1,3,2,11,66,12983,176,123,192,64,258,182,123,299,58,198,7,113,342,72,8376,122,20,19,2,3,28,8,36,8,56,43,2,48,127,395,4664,186,46,236,219,258,69,203,189,169,72,100,78,109,46,112,3929,272,40,4,31,2,97,36,5,35,56,2,237,1672,256,224,28,163,341,151,263,157,397,94,380,173,75,87,272,1194,133,6,112,1,6,2,26,25,64,8,40,57,106,525,150,248,125,269,264,256,357,153,64,152,283,1,2,2,454,154,39,1,1,64,151,242,1,18,99,1,36,607,55,54,110,225,108,37,1,144,162,137,107,21,360,362,18,51,25,43,1,3,6,1,27,7,45,326,32,103,50,124,155,39,180,143,33,116,46,7,151,120,19,4,2,4,110,2,7,4,9,4,27,216,323,148,1,1,2,1,47,113,150,1,2,144,16,4827,1,1,1,14];
numX = numel(x);
y = 1 : numX;
scatter(x,y);
```

The vector `y` is now explicitly created instead of reusing the variable that was created with a previous size in the past.  It also uses the colon operator to explicitly create this sequence instead of using a `for` loop.  That `for` loop is just not needed.  [`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) determines the total number of elements for an input matrix.  I don't like using `length` as a personal preference because it finds the number of elements in the largest dimension. This may work fine for vectors, but it has really made some hard to spot bugs in code that I've written in the past.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am used to loops in other programming languages and hence had to use a for loop. Thanks

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 Changed. Thanks.  BTW, if you want to avoid this problem with your current code, you can explicitly **clear** `y` before running your code.  Either do `clear y;` or `y = [];` before running this piece of code and it will be fine.... but I would still use the colon operator to create that sequence.

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 No worries.  I'll be honest and I came from a non-MATLAB programming background too before MATLAB... over time, this language became the best one that I know.... so if I was a beginner, I probably would have done the same thing you did.  Either way, happy MATLAB coding!